# Hiding title elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 forms section on a web page. Each form section has a seperate id with input elements contained within. I have a div outside of those form elements that serves as header for each section. I've written a script that checks if the form section has an input element that are labelled by the class name '.form-input'. Problem is when no form-inputs are found My script hides all Titles with the ".title-section" class name. I need to hide only the "title-section" that belongs to the form element. It would be easier if this title were contained within the form but it's outside as a seperate div.

```
$(function () {
    //If there is no form inputs hide title section
    // .lenght is truthy = true or false
    if (!$(".form-input").length) {
        $(".title-section").hide();
    }
});
```

See below html for structure

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="title-section">
                <h3>Hide Me 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="form-section">
                <div class="well">
                    <input class="form-input">
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share the complete html here please and ideally a jsfiddle link as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hiding all `.title-section` elements simply because `$('.title-section')` selects all elements matching that selector, regardless of whether there is a `.form-input` element that follows it. You therefore need some code that assesses whether or not there is a `.form-input` element following the `.title-section` element. Something like this would work:

```
var titlesToHide = $('.title-section').filter(function(){
    return $(this).next().find('.form-input').length === 0;
});

titlesToHide.hide();
```

I'm using jQuery's `.filter()` method to select the desired elements. In the code I wrote, it looks at each `.title-section` element, and then checks to see if the element right after it—`.next()`—has an element inside it with the class name `.form-input`. If it doesn't—`.length === 0`—the filter function returns `true`, thus including that `.title-section` element in the final collection.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hca1y15z/

Comment: Thanks, I actually thought of filtering and then tried to implement if else statement.